# How to fetch name of a link inside function in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have a `jsp` code where i call `javascript` function using anchor tag. My problem is suppose there are several links then by clicking on any link i want to fetch the name of the link which is clicked and display it in `javascript` function. My code is as follows:

```
<%@include file="dbconnection.jsp"%>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>

<HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>
</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H1></H1>
<script>
function displayData(ctr) {

switch (ctr) {

case 1:
$("a").hide();
<%ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select value from categoryAttributeTable;") ;  %>
<% 
int c=0; %>
$('#myDiv').append('<A1> Broadcast Video--> </A1>');
<% while(rs.next()){ 
    String link=rs.getString(1);
    c++;
%>
$('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
$('#myDiv').append('<first>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A id="disp" HREF ="javascript:NextData(<%=c%>)"><%=link%></A> </first>');
$('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');
<% } %>
$('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
$('#myDiv').append('<Button1><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="$(\'a\').show();;$(\'#myDiv\').empty();"></Button1>');
$('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');
$('#myDiv').append('<div id="Myd"></div>');
break;

case 2:
 break;

 }
}

</script>

 <TABLE>



<%ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select DISTINCT title from categoryInfoTable where CID in(select CID from categoryConfigTable where parentCID = 'NULL');") ;%>
        <% 
        int counter=0;
         while(resultset.next()){ 
            String link=resultset.getString(1);
            counter++;
        %>
        <TR>
           <TD>
           <a id = "display" onclick="javascript:displayData(<%=counter%>);" href="#"><%=link%></a> 
           </TD> 
        </TR>
        <% } %>


 </TABLE>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Here i am passing `<%=link%>` to anchor tag. I want to fetch which link is clicked and show it when i call function. In the above function i manually gave `$('#myDiv').append('<A1> Broadcast Video--> </A1>');`.
But i dont want to give it manually.Can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly what you are asking, you can add a click listener on your anchors (using [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/)), and by including a custom attribute to the link you can get the clicked anchor's attribute like this:

```
$("#outer a").on("click", function () {
    alert($(this).text() +" has data attribute : "+$(this).attr('customAttribute'));
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sx928bjz/)

Hope it helps

Comment: There are multiple results and i cant provide separate anchor tag for each one of them

Comment: In <%=link%>, i have around 15 records and i only want to fetch that name which i clicked

Answer (score 0):

This will give you <%=link%> value for the link clicked.

```
$("#display").on("click", function () {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

EDIT:

1. Remove onclick attribute from anchor tag.
2. Add "data" attribute in anchor tag and set counter value in this attribute instead of onclick.
3. Add below piece of code inside  tag.

   ```
   '$'(document).ready(function () {
       '$'("#display").on("click", function () {
           var linkName = '$'(this).html();
           var counter = '$'(this).attr("data");
       }); 
       //Call displayData function here and pass counter and linkName variables
   });
   ```

Comment: can u show me where to mention it in code i am totally new to jsp